# Adobe AIR Stage.contentsScaleFactor always 1 on iPhone4s and iPad mini

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, flash, air

My application is just a template AIR Mobile AS3 project from FlashDevelop: application.xml file, and a Main class.

In the Main class, I create a text field with `stage.contentsScaleFactor` value as a text after the first `Event.RESIZE`:

```
var textField:TextField = new TextField();
textField.appendText("Size: " + stage.stageWidth + " x " + stage.stageHeight + "\n");
textField.appendText("Scale: " + stage.contentsScaleFactor + "\n");
addChild(textField);
```

On my iPhone with retina support, i get

> Size: 960 x 640
>
> Scale: 1

for

```
<requestedDisplayResolution>high</requestedDisplayResolution>
```

and

> Size: 480 x 320
>
> Scale: 1

for

```
<requestedDisplayResolution>standard</requestedDisplayResolution>.
```

Almost the same for iPad,

> Size: 2048 x 1536
>
> Scale: 1

for *high*, and

> Size: 1024 x 768
>
> Scale: 1

for *standard*.

I'm compiling with the latest AIR SDK 18.0.0.142 (beta), `-swf-version=29`.
Same results for release AIR SDK 18.

For AIR 14 SDK and `-swf-version=25`, I get some garbage values for size (it looks like my swf width and height multiplied by what `contentsScaleFactor` should be), but still `1` for `contentsScaleFactor`.

**Edit:**
I have encountered various questions which mentioned `contentsScaleFactor` over the web (for example, [this one](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1367778)). They claim that `contentsScaleFactor` should be 2 on Retina display
That is how this property documented:

> Specifies the effective pixel scaling factor of the stage. This value
>   is usually 1 on standard screens and 2 on HiDPI (a.k.a Retina)
>   screens. When the stage is rendered on HiDPI screens the pixel
>   resolution is doubled; even if the stage scaling mode is set to
>   StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE. Stage.stageWidth and Stage.stageHeight
>   continue to be reported in classic pixel units. Note: this value can
>   change dynamically depending if the stage is on a HiDPI or standard
>   screen.

Also, with

```
<requestedDisplayResolution>standard</requestedDisplayResolution>
```

and `configureBackBuffer` with `wantsBestResolution` set to `true`, I still get 1024*768 buffer on iPad. I verified that by drawing sharp 256*256 texture on 128*128 quad - result is blurry. Then I doing the same with

```
<requestedDisplayResolution>high</requestedDisplayResolution>
```

I get sharp looking image of the same physical size.

**My actual questions are:**

- Is `contentsScaleFactor` supposed to be 2 on Retina iPad/iPhone? If so, are there some compiler/packager options I'm missing?
- How I can determine for `requestedDisplayResolution=standard` that my stage was scaled?
- And if `contentsScaleFactor` doesn't work on mobile, for what purpose this property is? Should it work, for example, on Mac with Retina display?

**Edit 2:**

On Mac with Retina display, `contentsScaleFactor` works just fine, reporting `2`.

Comment: You can't get the DPI out of devices.  You can figure out the DPI but devices don't simply give it to us (for some strange reason).  Your app shouldn't scale.  Scaling kills the cpu.  You scale things in your code yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Use Capability.screenDPI to get the DPI ratio, divide stage.stageWidth by screenDPI. On Ipad you'll get around 8 (one DPI unit = around 2 fingers of real estate), DPI gives you your density. Now compare both, non retina Ipad = 8 DPI units for 132 pixel/DPI, retina Ipad = 8 DPI units for 264 pixel/DPI (HD), etc ...

Comment: Yes, that is how i'm doing it now for IOS devices, but unfortunately, Capability.screenDPI is unreliable in general. It is always 72 on desktop, some "random" values on android, and doesn't take into account current monitor DPI, where stage is running (stage.contentsScaleFactor is documented as it should report such things).

Comment: values are not as random as you say on Android, whether from Flash or native those values will always be HD for HD devices, etc ... and that's what's important.

Comment: I have 480*320 android phone with 240 dpi as shown by Capability.screenDPI. And also 240 dpi for another 800*480 phone with almost the same physical screen size. Also, HD and hidpi are different concepts - i need to determine, for given screen resolution, say 1000, should i render 10 * 100px list items, or 5 * 200px items for hidpi.

Comment: you need to range your DPI values and assign categories. On Flex for example anything above 320 is considered hdpi and Flex handles only 3 categories. You can handle more categories if you wish but don't handle a dozen or any single dpi value as its own category. To get a more accurate dpi you can go native and write an ane but on some Android device (not the majority but it will happen) DPi values will still be returned incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments:

> Yes, that is how i'm doing it now for IOS devices, but unfortunately,
>   Capability.screenDPI is unreliable in general. It is always 72 on
>   desktop, some "random" values on android, and doesn't take into
>   account current monitor DPI

Maybe its not so much **[Dots Per Inch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dots_per_inch)** that you need but instead you are looking for **[Pixels Per Inch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixel_density)**?
**DPI** applies when printing as ink dots on paper. **PPI** means how many pixels against a real-world inch. Don't worry even the Wikipedia article admits *"... It has become commonplace to refer to **PPI as DPI**, even though **PPI refers to input resolution**"* (now we understand that ***DPI is printing resolution***)

This means you should forget `Capability.screenDPI` and instead start including the `Capabilities.screenResolutionX` (display width) and `Capabilities.screenResolutionY` (display height) numbers in your calculations.

Here's some code for feedback. Hopefully it will be useful to you in some way: 
 PS: Double-check the Flash traces by using a ruler against computer screen.

```
var scrn_W : uint = Capabilities.screenResolutionX;
var scrn_H : uint = Capabilities.screenResolutionY;
var scrn_DPI : uint = Capabilities.screenDPI;

var init_stageW : int = stage.stageWidth; var init_stageH : int = stage.stageHeight;

//Diagonal in Pixels
var scrn_Dg_Pix : Number = int( Math.sqrt( scrn_W * scrn_W + scrn_H * scrn_H ) );

//Diagonal in Inches
var scrn_Diag : Number = int( Math.sqrt( scrn_W * scrn_W + scrn_H * scrn_H ) ) / 100;

var scrn_PPI : uint = int( Math.sqrt( scrn_W * scrn_W + scrn_H * scrn_H ) ) / scrn_Diag;
//or scrn_PPI = scrn_Dg_Pix / scrn_Diag; //gives same result as above line of code

var dot_Pitch : Number = scrn_W / ( Math.sqrt( scrn_W * scrn_W + scrn_H * scrn_H ) ) / (scrn_Diag * 25.4) / scrn_W;

var scrn_Inch_W : Number = ( scrn_W / scrn_PPI ); var scrn_Inch_H : Number = ( scrn_H / scrn_PPI );

var result_Num : Number = 0; var temp_Pix_Num:Number = 0;
var testInch : Number = 0; var my_PixWidth : Number = 0; 

stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, resizeListener);  //just in case 


////////////////////
//// FUNCTIONS

function inch_toPixels( in_Num : Number) : Number
{
    temp_Pix_Num = in_Num;
    result_Num = scrn_PPI * temp_Pix_Num;
    return result_Num; 
}

function pixels_toInch( in_Num : Number) : Number
{
    temp_Pix_Num = in_Num;  
    result_Num =  temp_Pix_Num / scrn_PPI;
    return result_Num; 
}

function cm_toInch( in_CM : Number) : Number
{
    //inch = cm * 0.393700787; //from centimetre to inch
    result_Num = in_CM * 0.393700787; return result_Num; 
}

function inch_toCM( in_Inch : Number) : Number
{
    //cm = inch * 2.54; //from inch to centimetre
    result_Num = in_Inch * 2.54; return result_Num;
}


function resizeListener (e:Event):void 
{ 
    // Handle Stage resize here (ie. app window's Scale Drag / Minimize etc)
    //trace("new stageWidth: " + stage.stageWidth + " new stageHeight: " + stage.stageHeight);
}

///////////////
//// TRACES

trace("Stage Init Width  : " + init_stageW);
trace("Stage Init Height : " + init_stageH);

trace("Screen Width     : " + scrn_W);
trace("Screen Height    : " + scrn_H);
trace("Screen DPI       : " + scrn_DPI);
trace("Screen PPI       : " + scrn_PPI);

trace("Screen Diag      : " + scrn_Diag);
trace("Screen Diag Pix  : " + scrn_Dg_Pix);

trace("Dot Pitch        : " + dot_Pitch);
trace("Disp Width (inches)  : " + scrn_Inch_W );
trace("Disp Height (inches) : " + scrn_Inch_H );
```

Comment: Thanks, but I know how to make a workaround. I want to know when my application is running on Retina display. BTW this solution doesn't work on Android either: I have two Fly devices with identical screen sizes (differs in less than a fraction of centimeter) with 320*480 and 480*800 `Capabilities.resolution`, and both with `Capabilities.screenDPI=240`.

Comment: We used DPI because that's the property that's the issue - screenDPI.  screenDPI doesn't work.  PPI and DPI are totally analogous.  You can't get DPI, or PPI, or any physical measurement without knowing the physical dimensions of something - either a pixel or the display.

Answer (score 0):

How about make use of [Application.applicationDPI & Application.runtimeDPI](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/Application.html#applicationDPI) to calculate the actual scale factor?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't use Flex for my project.